# Cannot use JUnitCore

Tags: java, junit

I'm pretty new to java and unit testing and I'm experimenting with junit and so I watch tutorials and read blogs about it. From time to time there are things like PrimerClasses and TestSuites and everyone seems to have no problem using these kind of functionalities.

So when I try to use these too, my project cannot find JUnitCore or even the runner, where all that pretty stuff comes from and up to now I was not able to work out what the reason might be.

Comment: share code and error msg.

Comment: you MUST add lines of code, errors and exceptions you're facing

Comment: I try to use runWith() in the Mail class and theres nothing else but the bare standard Main class code in it. I dont get any. The error i get is "Cannot resolve symbol 'JUnitCore'" as I am not even able to import it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you added dependency of JUnit in your application?

If you are unable to find the classes then you should add proper dependencies.

If you have created the maven project, then add below lines in your pom file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
</dependency>
```

Or download the jar and add it to you project classpath.

Comment: I am working with IntelliJ, so to use JUnit i did literally nothing. I did not use any Maven or Gradle Dependency Managers, so I don't know where I should put the dependency tag.

Comment: First learn to use any IDE before starting any project. See the IntelliJ documentation to add local dependency. Download the JUNIT jar and add it in your project as local dependency.

Comment: I added JUnit 4.12 as jar to the project and dependencies and it works now. But souldn't the already as external library included JUnit 5 Lib contain the same features as older versions?

Comment: Didn't get you. Can you please elaborate your question?

Comment: Under 'External Librarys' in my project structure JUnit5 was already included and also I did set up some tests for one of my functions. I thought if i'm able to use @Test annotation and run tests manually from JUnit5. that the other functionalities like creating test suites or just using runWith() would also work. I'm surprised that it turns out that i have to include an older JUnit version to make these work.

Comment: You don't need to add jar from outside if its already present in External Library. But you need to include that External Library in your project dependency. You can refer IDE documentation to do the same.

Comment: Also if your problem is solved you may accept the answer (http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: In my project structure it already is added as dependency, still i also have to add the junit-4.12.jar to get access to specific imports.

Comment: Maybe I did something wrong when including JUnit5 in the first place. Thank you for your patience. You still helped me a lot.